# arbitrary parameters in a Spring-boot request

Tags: java, spring

Apologies up front. This should be a 100% google-able question, but I seem to be using the wrong vocabulary.

On an http query, parameters are passed as part of the url string:

```
curl http://my.host.com/controllerName/actionName?a=b&c=d&e=f&param1=apple&param2=oran
```

The application specifies a few parameters, and those could be optional:

```
public HttpEntity<MyResults> actionName(
        @RequestParam(value = "param1", required = true, defaultValue = "Electric Bulb") String param1,
        @RequestParam(value = "param2", required = false ) String param2
        ) throws SomeException { etc}
```

What I want is if the user passes in some set of params *other than what was specified*, to capture that in one or more strings to pass downstream. For example, in some languages the 'leftover' query parameters would be a map {param, value}.

Is this possible in Java's type system? If so, how? And what is the right name for them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure: pass the HttpServletRequest as argument, and use `request.getParameterMap()` to access all the parameters and their values.

Comment: And behold! A google on Spring boot parameter map returns exactly what you might think. Thanks!

Comment: How does that look in the browser http web address when you enter it manually?